# String manipulation in C converting a MAC address

Tags: c

I have `char *MAC="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:99"`.
In this string all the values are in "hex" format.

How can I store it into another string and remove first two numbers and last four numbers should like this:
`"ss.ttt.uu.vv"`.

Here ss is decimal of "cc", ttt is decimal of "dd" likewise.

```
#define DELIM ":"
int tok(char *str_to_tokenize)
{
 // char str_to_tokenize[] = "- Strtok is meant for - breaking up, strings with funny values. + 5";
  char *str_ptr;

  fprintf(stdout, "Split \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str_to_tokenize);

  str_ptr = strtok(str_to_tokenize, DELIM);
  for(; str_ptr != NULL ;){
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", str_ptr);
    str_ptr = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
  }

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  char* buffer="aa:bb:c:dd:ee:ff:gg";
  tok(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strtok()`, `snprintf()`.

Comment: @user95711 - It is worth you having a bash - might learn something.

Comment: I can spilt them but dont know how to convert them and merge as decimals

Comment: Look into scanf to convert strings to decimals.

Comment: but how to store this  "tokens" in to separate string variable than I  can convert into decimal?

Comment: This code might lead to a segmentation fault: You are passing a constant character buffer to strtok. But strtok modifies the buffer passed. In some environments this will lead in data aborts because you are modifying readonly values. Use `char buffer[] = "..."` instead. this will copy the initializer string into a modifyable buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a case for `sscanf()` and `snprintf()` to me.  However, the question is confusing:

> I have `char *MAC="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:99"`. In this string all the values are in "hex" format.
>
> How can I [...] remove first two numbers and last four numbers like this: "ss.ttt.uu.vv".

Are you counting digits or numbers?  If you're counting numbers, removing the first two means 'aa' and 'bb' are ignored, and removing the last four means 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', and '99' are ignored too.  If you're counting digits, then 'aa', 'ff' and '99' are ignored, leaving 4 numbers (8 digits) to be formatted into the 4-part dotted number.  On the whole, counting digits makes more sense.

You then say:

> Here ss is decimal of "cc", ttt is decimal of "dd" likewise.

If the first field of `ss.tt.uu.vv` is the decimal equivalent of `cc`, and the second is the decimal equivalent of `dd`, then:

- Where do `bb` and `ee` go?
- Are `uu` and `vv` in hex or decimal?

Assuming that what you're really after is:

- Convert the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th hex fields in `MAC` to integers.
- Present the result as `sss.ttt.uuu.vvv` with decimal equivalents of the hex values in the original order.

This might be implemented as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int bb, cc, dd, ee;
    const char *MAC = "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:99";
    char output[16] = "";

    if (sscanf(MAC, "%*x:%x:%x:%x:%x:", &bb, &cc, &dd, &ee) == 4)
        snprintf(output, sizeof(output), "%d.%d.%d.%d", bb, cc, dd, ee);

    printf("MAC = %s; result = %s\n", MAC, output);
    return(0);
}
```

The `%*x` conversion specification means 'read a hex integer and do not assign it to a variable'.

Example output:

```
MAC = aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:99; result = 187.204.221.238
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for...actually 99 was by mistake and ss.tt.uu.vv are just examples no connection between real value ad this (these all are decimals separated by DOT) . As I am very new in C I could not tell you what I wanted to do with the string. sorry for that.